# HTML5 canvas context does not update in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-canvas

*UPDATE: This has been submitted as a WebKit bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=246498*

*UPDATE: I added a code snippet with contributions by @Kaiido, the bug is more apparent on his [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7awL4fg3/).*

I've been experiencing a very weird HTML5 2D Canvas issue in Safari that is not present in Chrome or Firefox. This has started affecting a website that has been in production for 5 years.

I have canvas drawing code like this, which produces a flicker in some of the lines where color is not correctly applied:

```js
const canvasWidth = 600;
const gapBetweenLines = 5;
const nbrLines = canvasWidth / gapBetweenLines;
const canvasHeight = 100;

const canvas = document.getElementById('map');
canvas.width = canvasWidth;
canvas.height = canvasHeight;

// create an array of line objects, each with a with random color
let lines = [];
for (let i = 0; i < nbrLines; i++) {
  lines.push({
    index: i,
    x: i * gapBetweenLines,
    color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
    // force always 6 length
      .padStart(6, "0")
  });
}

// function to shuffle the given array in place
function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}

// draw lines on the canvas at specific intervals with the random colors
function drawLines() {
  const shuffledLines = [...lines];
  shuffle(shuffledLines);

  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for (let i = 0; i < nbrLines; i++) {
    const line = shuffledLines[i];
    ctx.strokeStyle = line.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(line.x, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(line.x, canvasHeight);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

// call the drawLines function every 100ms
setInterval(drawLines, 200);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Flickering Lines</h1>
    <canvas id="map"></canvas>
    <div id="lineinfo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Safari, the stroke colors do not consistently change to their proper `strokeStyle` value. It behaves as if some of the `strokeStyle` assignments are being ignored. All the lines draw, but many of them retain the color from prior loop iterations.

This seems like a fairly basic use case for `stroke()`, so I cannot figure out what I may be doing wrong here; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Double check all your `style.color` values, If there are too many of these, you could try something like `const lastColor = ctx.strokeStyle; ctx.strokeStyle = style.color; if (lastRawColor && lastRawColor !== style.color && ctx.strokeStyle === lastColor) { console.log(`${style.color} has an issue`);} lastRawColor = style.color` where `lastRawColor` is a simple variable you'd declare outside of the loop. This should let you know which values aren't supported.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did try that and didn't get any logs. The colors work fine if I do the .save() and .restore() so it's not an issue with the color values themselves. It's like the lines are being drawn with a previous color even though strokeStyle contains the value I set it to.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7awL4fg3/ There I get a few "invalid colors" in the console, for values that are definitely valid and even supported by Safari when not in the loop. That's a bug indeed, which also affects the latest Technology Preview. Let them know about it.

Comment: The bug has been reported, with a link in the question above.